# Changing php.ini upload sizes in a safe, minimal way

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, apache-httpd, php, nginx

When I want to change the famous `2M` scales for `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` in `php.ini`, I use the following two-line `sed` solution which is version agnostic (see asterisk):

```
sed -i 's/post_max_size \= .M/post_max_size \= 200M/g'             /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
sed -i 's/upload_max_filesize \= .M/upload_max_filesize \= 200M/g' /etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini
```

Is there an even shorter, more minimalist way to do the same two-objects change in a single command? Something that will still be safe, and version agnostic.

As a web server I use Nginx.

Comment: Use `vim` (or other editor) and add two `00` twice then save maybe? BTW, `php.ini` is in a different location on some servers. You can also set these values per `<VirtualHost>` and per `<Directory>` [in Apache](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) which is a more secure way to limit uploads instead of a server wide answer.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - instead of changing it in every single file, create an included file with the default settings, then have that file included in all such files (It looks like you're creating one per shared hosting site). Presto, problem solved *and* future-proofed.

Comment: I have only one environment with one web server on it. The upload size of 200 megabytes is just fine for all my sites so I've no problem with 1 fixed upload value for all sites (nice you brought this point up!). I just think 2M default is very miser and lame and 200M is way more comfortable for many users. Loading an external conf file seems to me redundant for that specific task and the simplest approach would be just to change the default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kludgy way to do both parameters at once is

```
sed -i 's/^(\w*[td]_max_\w*size\s*=\s*).M/\1200M/' filename(s)
```

First of all, according to this [List of php.ini directives](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php),
there are only three keywords that contain `_max_` and end with `size`:

- `imlib2.font_cache_max_size`
- `post_max_size`
- `upload_max_filesize`

Note that the letter immediately before the `_max_`
is different in each case:

- `imlib2.font_cache_max_size` → `e`
- `post_max_size`       → `t`
- `upload_max_filesize`    → `d`

so, by searching for `[td]_max_`, we can eliminate the first one.

The command in detail:

- `^` of course constrains the regular expression
  to match occurrences at the beginning of the line. 
  If you want to match strings that are not at the beginning of the line,
  remove the `^`. 
  Note: unless you add something to specify otherwise,
  this will cause the command to change lines that are commented out,
  which might be confusing.
- `\(…\)` identifies a group of characters. 
  We will use it to match everything up to
  (but *not* including) the parameter value (i.e., the number after the `=`).
- `\w*[td]_max_\w*size` matches

  - any number of “word” (alphanumeric) characters,
  - a `t` or a `d`,
  - `_max_`,
  - any number (possibly zero) of word characters, and
  - `size`.
- `\s*=\s*` matches any number of space characters (regular space or tab),
  an `=`, and any number of space characters again. 
  (You don’t need to say `\=`.)

  This is the end of the group, marked by `\)`.
- As you know, `.M` matches any character followed by `M`. 
  (You’re using this already.)
- `\1200M` looks confusing, but it’s just

  - `\1`, which replaces the characters in the `\(…\)` group with themselves,
  - followed by `200M`, which is what you want to replace
    the `nM` number with.

You don’t need the `g`
unless you expect to match multiple strings on the same line
(which is impossible if you anchor the regular expression
to the beginning of the line with `^`).

Replace *`filename(s)`* with your `/etc/php/*/fpm/php.ini` glob,
or any other filename or list of filenames.

Before doing the above, you should run

```
sed -n 's/^(\w*[td]_max_\w*size\s*=\s*).M/\1200M/p' filename(s)
```

which will show what the first command will do.